# Crystal Reports - inconsistent formatting

Tags: crystal-reports

We have a c# windows service generating reports from Crystal 11 RPT files.

This morning the service was restarted as normal, generated a couple of reports correctly then seems to have changed the line spacing in the headers of a table in one particular report, so the headers didn't fit correctly. The width of the text also changed, and some words wrapped where they would not normally wrap.

Some 20 reports were generated incorrectly then, roughly half an hour later, the reports went back to looking like normal.

Other RPT files were not affected.

The problem has not happened on previous days, so is not simply connected to the time.

Some of the reports had no rows in the table which was screwed up, so it's not simply a matter of data not fitting in the table either.

Can anyone help suggest an explanation for this, or is it just the kind of madness one expects from a product as hopeless as Crystal?

Answer (score 3):

Did you change your default printer or other printer settings for the printer being used by the report? If the printer that is selected in the report for printing is not found, the report will print to the default printer. This may cause the page settings to change based on the sizes and fonts supported by the printer.

Comment: Hi Huzefa - thanks for your reply - nothing was changed on the server generating reports.